# Made a function to send mail using PHPmailer. but it is not working

Tags: php, api, phpmailer

i made a php function to send mail using phpmailer. but, there is a problem in the function. it neither send mail nor shows error. please help me out. i'm fetching mail body and some other details from other functions and its working fine except it doesn't send mail and i think there must be some problem with the host,port,username,etc.
please help me out.
thanks

my funciton:

```
public static function sendEmail($data) {

        $r_error = 1;
        $r_message = "";
        $r_data = array();

        $q = "select * from config where type='email_detail'";
        $r = self::DBrunQuery($q);
        $row = self::DBfetchRow($r);
        $detail = json_decode($row['value'], true);

        include "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";


        if (!empty($data['email'])) {


            foreach ($data as $var) {
                $work_email = 'fahadansari12feb@gmail.com'; //$var['email_id']; 
                $name = 'fahad'; //$var['name'];
                $subject = $var['subject'];
                $body = $var['body'];
                $cc = $var['cc_detail'];
                $bcc = $var['bcc_detail'];
                $file_upload = $var['upload_file'];

                $mail = new PHPMailer;
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
                $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
                $mail->Host = '5.9.144.226'; //$detail['host'];
                $mail->Port = '2222'; //$detail['port'];
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username = 'fahadansari12feb@gmail.com'; //$detail['username']; //sender email address 
                $mail->Password = 'mypassword'; //$detail['password']; // sender email password
                $mail->setFrom('hr@excellencetechnologies.in', 'Excellence Technologies'); // name and email address from which email is send
                $mail->addReplyTo('hr@excellencetechnologies.in', 'Excellence Technologies'); // reply email address with name 
                $mail->addAddress($work_email, $name); // name and address to whome mail is to send
                if (sizeof($cc) > 0) {
                    foreach ($cc as $d) {
                        $mail->addCC($d[0], $d[1]);
                    }
                }
                if (sizeof($bcc) > 0) {
                    foreach ($bcc as $d2) {
                        $mail->addBCC($d2[0], $d2[1]);
                    }
                }
                $mail->Subject = $subject; // subject of email message 
                $mail->msgHTML($body); // main message 
                // $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
                //Attach an image file
                if (sizeof($file_upload) > 0) {
                    foreach ($file_upload as $d3) {
                        $mail->addAttachment($d3);
                    }
                }
//send the message, check for errors
                if (!$mail->send()) {
                    $row3 = $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                    $row3 = "Message sent";
                }
            }
        }


        if ($row3 != "Message sent") {

            $r_error = 1;
            $r_message = $row3;
            $r_data['message'] = $r_message;
        } else {
            $r_error = 0;
            $r_message = "Message Sent";
            $r_data['message'] = $r_message;
        }
        $return = array();
        $return['error'] = $r_error;
        $return['data'] = $r_data;
        return $return;
    }
```

Comment: Have you made absolutely sure that your script is reaching the `if (!$mail->send()) {` line?

Comment: its showig smtp connect error.

Comment: You need to look [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), and you need to google ["smtp connect() failed"](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS688US688&ei=nGKvWqrjOYfZjwSU5K6QDQ&q=phpmailer+smtp+connect%28%29+failed&oq=phpmailer+smtp+con&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0l2j0i20i263k1l2j0l3.213368.214716.0.217883.9.9.0.0.0.0.154.1063.0j9.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.9.1061...0i67k1.0.AkUPdRsiorw) -- if you still can't get it working, come back and discuss what problems you had when you tried those things, and why those things wouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You've not posted enough info, but I'm going to guess your problem. You're enabling TLS, but you're connecting to an IP address rather than a host name, so your host name will never match the name on the certificate and you will get a TLS validation failure on SMTP connections.

Connect to a named host with a valid certificate, or disable certificate checks (see PHPMailer docs for how to do that), though that's not recommended.

You're also using an old version of PHPMailer, so upgrade.